# Ruby on Rails Solr re-index error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sprockets, sunspot-rails

When i try to re index with Solr , i get this error

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.
Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then
use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
 (called from block in <class:Railtie> at /home/frcake/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/less-rails-2.7.1/lib/less/rails/railtie.rb:15)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You are using the a deprecated processor interface Less::Rails::ImportProcessor.
Please update your processor interface:
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
 (called from block in <class:Railtie> at /home/frcake/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/less-rails-2.7.1/lib/less/rails/railtie.rb:20)
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Sprockets::Helpers
/home/frcake/workspace/Site/brokerv1/brokr/app/uploader/image_uploader.rb:12:in `<class:ImageUploader>'
/home/frcake/workspace/Site/brokerv1/brokr/app/uploader/image_uploader.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/frcake/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/frcake/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:reindex => sunspot:reindex
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

- i have tried doing it with bundle exec rake , or straight rake
- i have deleted the solr files and restarted
- i have deleted the xml file and restarted

i think i pretty much have done everything with no   avail...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had an upload_image.rb which had those lines

```
  #include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  #include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper
```

commenting those out , made it work again!
for some reason this was keeping solr from reindexing!

Answer (score 2):

And for the warning message you can either downgrade sprokets version to 3.6.3

`gem "sprockets", '3.6.3'`

or use this version of less-rails gem:

`gem 'less-rails', git: 'https://github.com/MustafaZain/less-rails'`

https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/issues/122#issuecomment-259950149

Comment: Great! , i added the Less version and it works great! thanks tons!